# $\mathfrak{sp}(4,\mathbb{R})$ isomorphic to $\mathfrak{so}(5,\mathbb{R})$.

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

How to show this isomorphism?

In this [link (proposition 4)](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=Sl8OAGYRz_AC&pg=PA94&lpg=PA94&dq=so(5)%20isomorphic%20to%20sp(4)&source=bl&ots=8NvNQDuMtN&sig=WC9fXMxa47JIdAuWeyRw0DuUPss&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CBwQ6AEwAGoVChMI7aaY6daIyAIV7QfbCh1Xrgy-#v=onepage&q=so(5)%20isomorphic%20to%20sp(4)&f=false) there's a prescription on how to build a proof for the complex case, how to use this for the real part, and how to show that this is indeed a Lie algebra homomorphism, i.e that the Lie bracket is invariant under this mapping?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These algebras are not isomorphic, since $\mathfrak{so}(5,\mathbb R)$ is a compact real form of its complexification while $\mathfrak{sp}(4,\mathbb R)$ is a split real form of its complexification.

The basic source of isomorphism of that type is the representation of $\mathfrak{sp}(4,\mathbb R)$ on $\Lambda^2\mathbb R^4$. This has dimension $6$, but there is an invariant subspace $\Lambda^2_0\mathbb R^4$ of dimension $5$, the kernel of the symplectic form preserved by $\mathfrak{sp}(4,\mathbb R)$. Moreover, the wedge product defined a symmetric bilinear form on $\Lambda^2\mathbb R^4$ with values in $\Lambda^4\mathbb R^4\cong\mathbb R$, which is invariant under the action of $\mathfrak{sp}(4,\mathbb R)$. One easily verifies that the restriction of this to $\Lambda^2_0\mathbb R^4$ is non-degenerate but not positive definite (indeed it has split signature $(2,3)$). Hence the representation of $\mathfrak{sp}(4,\mathbb R)$ on $\Lambda^2_0\mathbb R^4$ actually defines a homomorphism to $\mathfrak{so}(2,3)$. This is non-zero and hence injective since $\mathfrak{sp}(4,\mathbb R)$ is simple and counting dimensions, one sees that it has to be surjective, too. Hence $\mathfrak{sp}(4,\mathbb R)$ is isomorphic to $\mathfrak{so}(2,3)$ rather than to $\mathfrak{so}(5)$.

Comment: I'll rephrase what I meant, the Lie group $SO(5) := \{  g\in GL(5, R) : g^T L_5 g = L_5 \}$ where $L_n$ is defined as the $n\times n$ matrix whose $(i,n-i+1)$ entry is one and all other entries are zero. Denote by $\mathfrak{so}(5)$ the respective Lie algebra. Now let $Sp(2n,R) := \{ g\in GL(2n,R) : g^t J_n g =J_n \}$, where $J_n = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & L_n \\ -L_n &0 \end{pmatrix}$; denote by $sp(2n,R)$ its Lie algebra. Then I want to show that the Lie algebras $sp(4,R)$ isomorphic to $so(5,R)$. does now this question make sense?

Comment: The matrix $L_n$ describes a split signature inner product on $\mathbb R^n$ (i.e. signature $(k,k)$ if $n=2k$ and $(k,k+1)$ if $n=2k+1$). The group you call $SO(5)$ is commonly called $SO(3,2)$. But the only important fact about the inner prdouct is its signature, all inner products of the same signature lead to isomorphic groups. Replacing $\mathfrak{so}(5)$ by $\mathfrak{so}(3,2)\cong \mathfrak{so}(2,3)$) your question is fine. I have answered it by describing $\mathfrak{sp}(4,\mathbb R)$ as all endomorphisms of a 5-dim. space which are skew symmetric for an inner product of signature (2,3).

Comment: How do I verify that "...One easily verifies that the restriction of this to $\Lambda^2_0\mathbb R^4$ is non-degenerate but not positive definite"? thanks.

Comment: There are abstract reasons (basically, the complementary line is spanned by a symplectic form on the dual space, which has nonzero wedge product with itself) but you can also just compute: If you take the standard basis $\{e_1,\dots,e_4\}$ of $\mathbb R^4$ and the standard symplectic form $\omega$ with $\omega(e_1,e_3)=\omega(e_2,e_4)=1$, then $\Lambda^2_0\mathbb R^4$ is spanned by $e_1\wedge e_2$, $e_1\wedge e_4$, $e_2\wedge e_3$, $e_3\wedge e_4$ and $e_1\wedge e_3-e_2\wedge e_4$. Then just compute the matrix of mutual inner products of these basis elements.

Comment: Is there a way to show this without using the symplectic form $\omega$?

Comment: The 5-dimensional subspace that we are talking about would not be there without a symplectic form. The statement does not depend on the choice of symplectic form (the "general" argument I sketched in my last comment applies to any symplectic form), but you need some symplectic form.

Comment: How is the inner product on these basis vectors defined? I mean I don't remember how to compute the inner product of wedges' product; thanks.

Comment: The inner product is wedge product. The wedge product for two forms is commutative, and in case of a 4-dimensional space it has values in a one-dimensional space, which is trivialized (for the choices I suggested) by $e_1\wedge e_2\wedge e_3\wedge e_4$. For example, $e_1\wedge e_2$ is perpendicular to all other basis vectors except for $e_3\wedge e_4$, with which it has inner product one.

Comment: I can deduce from this that $sp(4,R)$ has an irreducible representation of dimension 5, but how do I know how does this representation is defined in order to find its weights and highest weight? thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29451/discussion-between-andreas-cap-and-mathematicalphysicist).

Comment: I added a new question in the chat, hope you can reply to me there. thanks.